# Java String Replace '&' with &amp; but not &amp; to &amp;amp;

Tags: java, regex, string, replace, ampersand

I have a large String in which I have & characters used available in following patterns -

```
A&B
A & B
A& B
A &B
A&amp;B
A &amp; B
A&amp; B
A &amp;B
```

I want to replace all the occurrences of & character to `&amp;`
While replacing this, I also need to make sure that I do not mistakenly convert an `&amp;` to `&amp;amp;`. How do I do that in a performance savvy  way? Do I use regular expression? If yes, please can you help me to pickup the right regular expression to do the above?

I've tried following so far with no joy:

```
data = data.replace(" & ", "&amp;"); // doesn't replace all &
data = data.replace("&", "&amp;");   // replaces all &, so &amp; becomes &amp;amp;
```

Comment: You could change all the `&amp;` to `&` and then change all the `&` to `&amp;`.

Comment: Do you have other escape characters like `&nbsp;` for instance?

Answer (score 48, accepted):

You can use a regular expression with a *negative lookahead*.

The regex string would be `&(?!amp;)`.

Using `replaceAll`, you would get:

```
A&amp;B
A &amp; B
A&amp; B
A &amp;B
A&amp;B
A &amp; B
A&amp; B
A &amp;B
```

So the code for a single string `str` would be:

```
str.replaceAll("&(?!amp;)", "&amp;");
```

Comment: You can use `&(?![a-z]{1,6};)` so that `&bull;` doesn't turn into `&amp;bull;`, for example.

Comment: &146; is changed to &amp;146;  so this one worked for me /&(?![a-z0-9]{1,7};)/&amp;/

Answer (score 7):

You can try this, it should work:

```
data = data.replaceAll("&amp;","&").replaceAll("&","&amp;");
```

That way you first replace all `&amp;` with `&` so all you'll have is `&`, and then, you replace all of them with `&amp;`.